# want to create a fixed deposit calculator(quaterly) using javascript in joomla chronoforms

Tags: javascript, joomla3.0, chronoforms

I am trying to display results after calculating fixed deposit maturity value based on compound interest formula. I am trying this with Joomla Chronoforms. Have also tried with Math.pow. Still not wrking.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(jQ) {
  jQ('#tenure_month').keyup( calc );
jQ('#cmpnd_anually').keyup( calcu );
var to_years;
 function calc() {    

to_years = jQ('#tenure_month').val();
    to_years = parseFloat(to_years) / 12;
    to_years = to_years.toFixed(1);
  jQ('#years').val(to_years);

};

 function calcu() {
var dep;
var rate_int;
var cmp_int;
dep = jQ('#deposit_amt').val(); 
dep = parseFloat(dep);

rate_int = parseFloat(jQ('#rate_int').val() / 400));
rate_int = rate_int.toFixed(1);

cmp_int =  dep * (1 + rate_int) ^ 4 * t_years;
  jQ('#cmpnd_anually').val(cmp_int);

};  
});
```

But not getting output. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly you need to debug your code:

- There is an extra ) in this line `rate_int =
  parseFloat(jQ('#rate_int').val() / 400));`
- t_years isn't defined in this line `cmp_int =  dep * (1 + rate_int) ^
  4 * t_years;`
- and you are using `jQ('#cmpnd_anually')` both for input and output

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I modified my code. Now its working. But the output diifers in decimal pointing. I am trying to calculate fixed deposit maturity value quaterly based on compound interest. This is my code: